# GITFLOW Linux Installation Issue

Tags: linux, git, github, git-flow

I changed my OS from Windows to Linux. In Windows, I didn't have any issue installing gitflow. I'm a newbie at Linux and stuck at installing gitflow.

I used

```
 wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/raw/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | sudo sh
```

and also tried

```
wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/raw/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | sudo bash
```

but got this error:

```
woppi@woppi-ThinkCentre-M80:~$ wget --no-check-certificate -q -O -       
https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/raw/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | sudo sh
[sudo] password for woppi: 
### gitflow no-make installer ###
Installing git-flow to /usr/local/bin
Cloning repo from GitHub to gitflow
Cloning into gitflow...
error: Failed connect to github.com:80; Connection refused while accessing 
http://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
Updating submodules
cd: 78: can't cd to gitflow
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
install: cannot stat `gitflow/git-flow': No such file or directory
install: cannot stat `gitflow/git-flow-init': No such file or directory
install: cannot stat `gitflow/git-flow-feature': No such file or directory
install: cannot stat `gitflow/git-flow-hotfix': No such file or directory
install: cannot stat `gitflow/git-flow-release': No such file or directory
install: cannot stat `gitflow/git-flow-support': No such file or directory
install: cannot stat `gitflow/git-flow-version': No such file or directory
install: cannot stat `gitflow/gitflow-common': No such file or directory
install: cannot stat `gitflow/gitflow-shFlags': No such file or directory
```

I followed github's git installation and also nvie's gitflow installation. I can't figure out what I missed.

I appreciate any help! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I forked git-flow and added bug fixes and functionality. Besides that I changed the URL structure for the above instructions as I noticed github had changed it's URL.

```
wget --no-check-certificate -q -O - https://raw.github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh | sudo bash
```

Answer (score 0):

The important line is:

```
error: Failed connect to github.com:80; Connection refused while accessing 
http://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git/info/refs
```

Try doing:

```
wget http://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git/info/refs
```

and fix whatever errors arise.